# ImportXML function after login

Tags: authentication, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

Is there any way to importXML data to a sheet from a site that needs a login?

(I have the user/pass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the site supports [BasicAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), you can insert the credentials in the userinfo part of the URL. Otherwise I don't believe it's possible, since you cannot directly modify request headers or the request body.